# How can I run my dse spark app with python on a server while closing my terminal?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, datastax-enterprise

this is my submit command and I don't know how to run it in the background with my terminal window closed：

dse spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 2 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.4.1 --jars /spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.4.1.jar /sparktest.py

Comment: the nohup does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, the first is to use a terminal session manager like https://tmux.github.io/ or https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ which will keep the terminal alive when you disconnect

Another is to use http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup before your command

Comment: this is error:Error: Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters.

Answer (score 1):

Try add '&' to the end of command:

```
spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 2 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.4.1 --jars /spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.4.1.jar /sparktest.py &
```